# What is advantage of using LESS variables

Tags: less

What is advantage of using `LESS` variables for changing properties like;

```
@Margin-10: 10px;
@Margin-12: 12px;
@Margin-19: 19px;
@Margin-110: 110px;
@Margin-189: 189px;
@Margin-115: 115px;
@Margin-150: 150px;
.................and so on.
```

And creating those variables which will not be alter in future.

```
@PullLeft: left;
@PullRight: right;
```

I am re-factoring the `LESS` in my application which has too many CSS properties which are using variables for above scenarios. Is there any advantage of using variables in this case?

Comment: For the first set, I agree with Darren's answer. It looks very wierd. For the second set, can't see any need for a variable. Variables are better used in places where you know the same value is required for multiple properties within different selectors and want to have one common place for maintaining them so that any modification to it in future becomes easier to make. Finally, I also think this question might attract opinion based answers.

Comment: I agree that there could be a lot of opinion based stuff flying around on this!  One thing I want to add, though, is that the second set is the same as the first.  In both cases the specifics of the definition have bled out into the name of the variable, making neither set desirable for the same reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its highly discouraged to use the name of variable same as value. The purpose of using variables is that if there is a change required then **modification** is minimal. e.g you have declared a variable @Container-width: 100px and you are using it in 10 files. So if you want to change its value to 200px then you would simple have to change value nothing more.

There are two disadvantages of using variables names as you suggest:

1. If you want to change the variable @Margin-10 value to say 15 e.g @Margin-10: 15 it would look odd.
2. If you are declaring variables for each value then there is no benefit of declaring it as variable because you have to modify it on several places (which is not fulfilling the purpose of variables)

Now coming to the variable name @PullRight or @PullLeft. Again there is no benefit of using such names, as the values (left, right, top , bottom) are limited not variable. So I would suggest that you don't create variables but use values as it is.

Create variable names on the basis of their functionality. Use noun and verbs.

Answer (score 6):

I think we may have a hammer in the house with those variables.  Having them named so specifically is problematic both because it doesn't really work with semantic concepts of layouts AND because if you were to change some of them, total chaos would soon ensue.  Just imagine:

```
@margin-189: 27px;
@margin-115: 46px;
```

I had trouble typing that even as an example.  I feel something like the shower scene from The Crying Game.

No, these variables are an example of when your only tool is a hammer, all you see are nails.

More correct might be something more semantically flavored, like:

```
@container-margin-left: 36px;
@panel-margin-left: 20px;
```

Those at least speak to how your site will be styled AND if the values were to change, it would not result in an immediate maintenance trainwreck.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as using variables in any language. You can simply change them whenever you want.

Now you can think - they will never change, but in future you may want to make some changes. You may even move some CSS to another project where you decide to make some changes. Using variables you will do it it a minute.

Another example. Let's assume you have the following code in CSS:

```
#page {
  width: 800px;
}
#content {
 width: 600px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
}
```

now you decide to change `#page` width to `780px`

SO you change it:

```
#page {
  width: 780px;
}
#content {
 width: 600px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 200px;
}
```

and now you have a problem - you need to look in the whole file what's wrong (in real file it won't be so easy as in example above).

Using variables you could have:

```
@page-width: 800px
@content-width: 600px;
@sidebar-width: @page-width - @content-width;
```

so without a problem you can change the value or make small modification in those 3 lines.

However in the example from question I think it hasn't been done as it should.  If you define:

```
@Margin-10: 10px;
@Margin-12: 12px;
@Margin-19: 19px;
```

you expect that `Margin-10` is 10 unit margin but you can decide to change the value for let's say 11 and you can have:

```
@Margin-10: 11px;
@Margin-12: 15px;
@Margin-19: 24px;
```

It will make you completely mess, because in fact even if you look at this file, you now don't know what is `Margin-10` variable and what's its purpose. It has even other value than its name suggests so you don't really know what to expect and you again need to look at whole CSS source.

So variables are useful but they should have names that you can easily remember and know what's their purpose. You should never connect variable name with variable value because value can change and you will get useless name.

However it's also possible in above example that someone defined those margins even not to change their values but to change their units, for example for using em:

```
@Margin-10: 10em;
@Margin-12: 12em;
@Margin-19: 19em;
```

However I still think it's not the best solution because it's limiting re-usage this file